# JQuery Tablesorter, use variable in sortlist

Tags: jquery

I have a HTML table computed out of SQL query result.
Number of columns keep varying. Last column is "Total". 
I want to present the table sorted by last column, descending.

Could anybody help me on how to achieve this?

All examples I see on internet have hard-coded column numbers in sortlist line.

I tried following... (didn't work)

```
var tableId = this.id;
var lastCol = $('#'+tableId).find('tr')[0].cells.length;
$('#'+tableId).tablesorter(
{
headers: {
       0: { 
       sorter: false
       }
},
sortList:[[lastCol,1],[1,0]],
widgets: ['zebra']
});
```

Needless to say... I am a newbie.
Any help/suggestion is appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this to get the last column:

```
var lastCol = $('#'+tableId+' tr:first td:last').index();
```

This should get the correct index of the last column...

Comment: Thanks for the tip on correct index! `var lastCol = $('#'+tableId).find('tr')[0].cells.length -1;` worked for me :)

Comment: Hi, no problem. Sorry - I had put up slightly incorrect code. Fixed it now if any good for you.